# shorthand way to display the added percentage onto a given number with the correct output

Tags: javascript

Okay, So before you criticise, Yes i have the desired output:

```js
var interest = prompt("Enter a percentage using a decimal Number...");
var interestRate = interest*100;
var startCash = 10000;
var total = startCash*interestRate/100+startCash;
var month = 1;

console.log("Starting Money: £" + startCash);
console.log("Interest Earned: " + interestRate + "%");
console.log("Total Amount: £" + parseInt(total));
console.log("This is Month: " + month);
```

There are a lot of answers on how to convert decimals into percentages, but hardly any to add that percentage to a starting number. Yes sure, if we know the percentage beforehand its easy enough, but I'm trying to do it on a user input so the percentage can be random.

I have the effect I am after, I am just asking if this is the correct way to do it or if there is a shorter way of doing it. I am relatively new to javascript as you can probably tell.

Also is there a way so they can only enter decimal numbers, to ensure the code stays on the desired output?

Comment: If(typeof interest==number)

Comment: **do not use document.write** -- it's an incredibly old, low level API that is absolutely not meant for modern Javascript, and *absolutely doesn't do what you think it does* (it does a pipe write to your document. Are you running this after DOM completion? Congratulations, it also wiped your document. By design). Use `console.log`, and look at your console.

Comment: Like i said i am new(ish) to javascript, but i have always been shown to do it with document.write, This is for testing purposes, on a blank document anyway so wouldn't make any difference right now, However i thank both you and @Oriol, You have shown me another way to look at it.

Comment: @Ricky: Re your now-deleted question about `document.write` vs. `console.log`: If you use `document.write` any time after the initial parsing of the HTML page, it implies `document.open`, which will wipe out the page content. So for instance, in an event handler, or a timer callback, or... *"Saying that, for Testing purposes...is it still better to use console.log, or is it better to use document.write?"* It's better to use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser. But if for some reason you need logging-style debugging (sometimes it comes up), `console.log` is preferred, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly shorter is:(Edited to do parsing of the prompt first)

```js
var interest = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a percentage using a decimal Number..."));
var startCash = 10000;
var total = startCash*(interest+1);
var month = 1;

console.log("Starting Money: £" + startCash);
console.log("Interest Earned: " + interest*100 + "%");
console.log("Total Amount: £" + parseInt(total));
console.log("This is Month: " + month);
```

Actually given the additional parsing needed with this method, I think I quite like your original approach too.

Comment: Where is `interestRate` defined?

Comment: Yes, well noted Clyde! I've made the change. It's a choice if you want to define interestRate, or inline just the once

Comment: That doesn't work, It throws the var Total out, it gives a value of 2510 instead of 12500, I can only seem to get the right value if i do total=startCash*interest+startCash

Comment: Does the above change work for you? (I should have checked if it gave the right answer first!) Probably your original approach is just as good though

Comment: I'm lazy :) just trying to be lazier :), So your method works properly now, Just out of curiosity what does the +1 do on (interest+1), and is there a way how you can ensure only decimals are placed in the prompt?

Comment: The +1 means add the original starting cash to the amount you get by interest: `startCash + startCash * interest`. So exactly the same in value as you did originally (if you replace `interestRate/100` by `interest`)

Comment: Building on brigysl's comment below, to do the parsing you can use this (or something similar, depending what check you would like) `var interest
do {
interest = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a percentage using a decimal Number..."));
}
while (isNaN(interest) || interest > 1 || interest < 0);`

Comment: **do not use document.write**

Comment: Do not use `parseFloat`, it's harmful. You can coerce to a number with the unary `+`.